# Check if an argument is a dictionary or not in Tcl

Tags: dictionary, tcl, catch-block

I want  have a proc which does something if its' argument is a Tcl 8.5 and above dictionary or not.
I could not find anything straightforward from Tcl dict command.
The code which I could get working is:

```
proc dict? {dicty} { 
    expr { [catch { dict info $dicty } ] ? 0 : 1 }
}
```

Is there anything w/o using catch, something built in?
Thanks.

Comment: You can try checking the `tcl_version` variable and apply a condition whether the version is greater than or equal to 8.5 or not to avoid this .

Comment: Relevant: [Determine type of a variable in TCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428032/determine-type-of-a-variable-in-tcl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test if a value is a dictionary by seeing if it is a list and if it has an even number of elements; *all* even length lists may be used as dictionaries (though many are naturally not canonical dictionaries because of things like duplicate keys).

```
proc is-dict {value} {
    return [expr {[string is list $value] && ([llength $value]&1) == 0}]
}
```

---

You can peek at the actual type in Tcl 8.6 with `tcl::unsupported::representation` but that's ***not advised*** because things like literals are converted to dictionaries on the fly. The following is legal, shows what you can do, and shows the limitations (

```
% set value {b c d e}
b c d e
% tcl::unsupported::representation $value
value is a pure string with a refcount of 4, object pointer at 0x1010072e0, string representation "b c d e"
% dict size $value
2
% tcl::unsupported::representation $value
value is a dict with a refcount of 4, object pointer at 0x1010072e0, internal representation 0x10180fd10:0x0, string representation "b c d e"
% dict set value f g;tcl::unsupported::representation $value
value is a dict with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x1008f00c0, internal representation 0x10101eb10:0x0, no string representation
% string length $value
11
% tcl::unsupported::representation $value
value is a string with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x1008f00c0, internal representation 0x100901890:0x0, string representation "b c d e f g"
% dict size $value;tcl::unsupported::representation $value
value is a dict with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x1008f00c0, internal representation 0x1008c7510:0x0, string representation "b c d e f g"
```

As you can see, types are a bit slippery in Tcl (by design) so you're strongly advised to not rely on them at all.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is flawed because Tcl has dynamic type system where the actual type of a value is able to morph dynamically and depends on the commands applied to it—observe:

```
$ tclsh
% info pa
8.5.11
% dict info {a b}
1 entries in table, 4 buckets
number of buckets with 0 entries: 3
number of buckets with 1 entries: 1
number of buckets with 2 entries: 0
number of buckets with 3 entries: 0
number of buckets with 4 entries: 0
number of buckets with 5 entries: 0
number of buckets with 6 entries: 0
number of buckets with 7 entries: 0
number of buckets with 8 entries: 0
number of buckets with 9 entries: 0
number of buckets with 10 or more entries: 0
average search distance for entry: 1.0
% llength {a b}
2
% string len {a b}
3
%
```

As you can see, the same value `{a b}` is a dictionary, a list and a string: in each case, the value acquires its "real" type in the very moment a Tcl command expecting a value of certain type converts the "default" type of the value, which is string, to the one the command operates on.

You should understand by now that trying to make a call `dict? {a b}` has little sence as the value `{a b}` is a perfect dict as well as a perfect list as well as a perfect string, and it could be, say, a perfect tuple if there are custom commands in the current interpreter working on tuples (lists of fixed length).

Hence the real approach you should take is to just blindly use `dict` command on those values passed to your commands you expect to contain dictionaries.  If a user will manage to pass to your command something which is not interpretable as a dictionary, the `dict` command will fail, and that's a good thing to do as such an error is not really recoverable (it's a programming error).

Any attempt to count on a value's specific type is going again the grain of the very idea of the Tcl's implicit/dynamic typing.  It's even true for the Tcl C API.

---

If you really meant to ask how to be sure the current Tcl version *supports* `dict` command, and not about the type of a particular value, test the Tcl's version somewhere at startup and save this as a flag, like this:

```
set hasDicts [expr {[package vcompare [info tclversion] 8.5] >= 0}]
```

But note that your code relying on the `hasDicts` value is now in some gray zone because if the user is not supplying you values you process with the `dict` command then what command you use to process them?

Please also note that the `dict` command can be added to a Tcl 8.4 interpreter in the form of the loadable module (see [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/dict)).

Comment: This language strength (everything is a string) is also it's downfall, and it's limitation to future growth....

Comment: @user1134991, I disagree. While in the end I prefer more strict typing (my favorite programming language at the moment is [Go](http://golang.org)) Tcl's approach to typing in beautiful.  You appear to just have a certain mental barrier regarding this approach.  That's why I begun with stating that the very premise of your question is flawed: seasoned Tcl programmers simply do not compe up with a need to test a value's type in the first place: they just *treat* values as being of certain type throughout the lives of those values, and the whole thing just works.

Comment: @user1134991,  If you need more guidance on this, just ask on the Tcler's chat or on `comp.lang.tcl` newsgroup/mailing list -- I'm afraid this sort of discussion does not really fit the SO's paradigm, and thus redirecting.

Comment: @user1134991, to put this in a different perspective... You usually just *define* which set of features your program has to rely on and state that by `package require`-ing particular versions of external packages *and the Tc interpreter itself* -- by saying something like `package require Tcl 8.5`: this directive will fail right away on Tcl < 8.5. Now you just use `dict` everywhere you intend it to, and state that in the docs for procs constituting your public API, if any. And again, it just works.